# semi variogram analysis for buidings in raster dem with penta spherical model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, variogram

I am carrying out semi-variogram analysis in arcgis using geostatistical tool
on a DEM. the plot gives the semi variance and lag distance. I want to know at what elevation of DEM the sill value is flatenning or is constant.

[image: Palm Springs commercial photography]

[image: Palm Springs commercial photography]

Comment: Did-you  know the geostatistical analysis out of Arcgis?

Answer (score 1):

The semivariogram is a function of *difference* in DEM values over distance. The x-axis is *distance*, the y-axis is something like average height difference for two random points that distance apart. Close together points have a small difference on average, far apart points have a large difference on average.

So the semivariogram doesn't level off at a value of the DEM (a height), but at a value of *distance*.

You can compute this if you have the parameters and the formula for the semivariogram, and its most likely related to the "lag distance" you mention. Typically that's the distance where the semivariance has risen to some fraction of the semivariance at large distance, but it depends on the actual formula for the fitted semivariogram, which you haven't given (exponential, spherical, gaussian are typical examples).

If you can include a screenshot of the plot and all the output then we might be able to do this.

Comment: it is  a penta-spherical semi-variogram .but where to attach the screen shots no option here or else I have to post a fresh querry attaching the formula and plot.

Comment: Without enough reputation score you'll need to upload them to any image host, then edit your question and post a link.